How can I improve this question's clarity?
I just asked a question about making queries to an array. It has been closed as 'needs more focus'. However, I haven't (or I can't see) any feedback or reasons for why it isn't clear.
I've detailed the exact problem, provided bounds, constraints on the variables, have an MRE of what the code I currently have is. I've listened to the people in the comments and edited the question to add whatever they've specified I should add.
I really can't see anything else I can improve. Can anyone provide some helpful, constructive feedback on how to make the question clearer?

Agreed that it's not close-worthy, but it's not particularly good, either. Perhaps adding a quick summary of the literature you reviewed (and reasons for rejecting) would better establish where you in solving this problem are and how you got there.

@user4581301 Thanks a lot! If you don't mind, may I ask if there's anything about the question that is unclear?

I think it's simply asking too much. You clearly have a very complex requirement of a sort that very few other people would have (unless you can explain the practical use case). I admit I misunderstood the first couple of times.

Does that make it not a good question, by site rules?

@KarlKnechtel In my opinion, it's just asking for a solution to a very clear and specific problem. The difficulty of a question should not be grounds for closing.

@Unmitigated Complexity is not the same thing as difficulty.

The question is clear and should not have been closed as 'unclear' or 'needs more focus'.  It was and is a valid question, and the requirements are clear enough.  Sorry that that happened to you.  Sometimes people make mistakes.  Thank you for handling it in such a patient and constructive manner.
It is open now.
Your behavior has been exemplary from everything I can see, in making polite requests for constructive feedback, answering the clarification requests, and revising the question accordingly.  I don't think you're doing anything wrong.  Keep up the good work.
My only feedback would be to flag comments as 'no longer needed' once you have addressed them (I realize you might already be doing this).
For future reference: This is more of an algorithms question than a coding question.  While algorithms questions are normally on-topic on Stack Overflow, my experience is that the quality of responses you get on SO to algorithms questions can be variable: sometimes outstanding (as in this case), sometimes lousy, and occasionally overly focused on the code.  Computer Science Stack Exchange is another place you can ask algorithms questions, where you might have better luck at getting answers that are focused on the algorithmics rather than on the implementation.  (But don't cross-post on both SO and CS.SE.)  No pressure, just letting you know about another resource in case it is helpful.
